# Compare rows from 2 dimension arrays and replacing them with empty rows - Google Scripts

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script

Array currentlySaved contains a range with data saved on my sheet. Array data contains rows that I want to remove from the sheet.

I'm to compare array rows, but the script keeps running without returning an output.

Also, instead of deleting rows from currentlySaved, I'm trying to replace them with empty rows. I did this because I fear that deleting rows will change the size of the Array and cause it to skip information.

For instance if currentlySaved[3] is deleted, currentlySaved[4] becomes the new currentlySaved[3]. Because the loop already ran through i=3, what used to becurrentlySaved[4] will be ignored.

This is what I have right now:

```html
  
  var emptyRow = []; //an empty row to replace deleted data
  
for (i=0; i<currentlySaved.length;i++) {
  for (j=0; j<data.length;i++) {
    if ( currentlySaved[i] == data[j]) {
      
      
     currentlySaved[i] =emptyRow;
  
  
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks folks!

Edit: added screen shots of report and savedDB. I am sorry that they are cut out, the data on the sheets is confidential.
How it is supposed to work: If a driver on report is deleted, his row on savedDB should be deleted.

Example:

Report will display this information obtained from savedDB

checkbox     terminal   driver-number   name
 FALSE        New York        1234            John

the user marks a checkbox as true and clicks the delete button on the top of the page.

The script must then find a row on savedDB that matches this exact information and either remove it or change its values to "".

[report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTYCY.png)

[savedDB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDuFR.png)

Comment: I think that providing the sample input and output values you want will help users think of your solution.

Comment: Advice regarding your concern. If you start from the bottom and work your way up, the delete  of rows should be safe and not interfere with your counter.

Answer (score 1):

Two things:
The first is that it seems like you are iterating i on the second loop rather than j.

```
for (j=0; j<data.length;**i++**) {
```

This might be part of the issue.

Would something like what I have here work for what you are doing?

```
function deleteRows() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet()

  var range = sheet.getRange("A4:A10");
  var data = [1,4,6,8];
  var lastRangeRow = range.getLastRow();
  var firstRangeRow = range.getRow();

  for (var i=lastRangeRow;i > firstRangeRow - 1;i--) {
    for (j=0; j<data.length;j++) {
      if ( i == data[j]) {
        sheet.deleteRow(i);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, iterating i was indeed part of the problem. Now the loop is no longer endless.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're trying to accomplish:

```
function replaceRowsWithEmptyRows() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh1=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var rg=sh1.getDataRange();
  var dA=rg.getValues();
  var csA=dA[0].slice(0);//csA has a copy of whats in dA[0]
  var mtA=csA.map(function(el){return ''});//mtA has csA.length nulls
  for(var i=0;i<dA.length;i++) {
    if(csA.join('')==dA[i].join('')) {//comparing the contents of the arrays
      dA[i]=mtA;//if they match then replace current row with empties
    }
  }
  var sh2=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  sh2.clear();
  sh2.getRange(1,1,dA.length,dA[0].length).setValues(dA);//Displayed results in Sheet2
}
```

Sheet1:

[image]

Sheet2:

[image]